# Why there are 2 then blocks in fetch call in React?

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise

I am using fetch api to bring data from back-end and it is working as expected for me. However I am not able to figure out why there is a need of 2 then blocks in fetch call.

Comment: Could you share your code, because this could be several things like for example the `.json()` is also a promise which should be resolved resulting in an additional `.then`. This could be avoided using the `async/await` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I am using  .json()

Answer (score 11):

[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) uses promises and it takes a request as a parameter and return a promise that resolve to a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) Object that response object has information about the server response like **status code** and **headers** and the body of the response which is the data you want , and some of the methods on that [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)  Object return **[Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)** too so you need to make another **then** block , methods like **response.json()** **response.text()** **response.blob()** , so this is why you need two **then** blocks , the first resolve the **response** from the server and the second get the data from the response .
learn more

[Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

[javascript Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

[Using Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Another example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json#example

Answer (score 4):

Fetch returns Promise ([Easy article of Promise](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp)) and you need to resolve promise to access data. To resolve a promise, you need to use then()

**A basic fetch example:**

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data, 'Data'));
```

> In the above example, fetch returns promise, so it is resolved in
> first then() where it is getting response object that is
> representation of the entire HTTP response. So to extract the JSON
> body content from the Response object, we need to use the json()
> method, which returns a second promise that resolves with the result
> of parsing the response body text as JSON. [Click here for More
> Detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Here I run a fetch using online js compiler and show the output in console. Please have a look at description in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing your code, I assume the promise being returned and reconciled in the first "then" block has another asynchronous call with it's own return. For instance...

```
foo() //returns a promise
.then(() => { // called when "foo" resolves the promise
    return bar();
})
.then(() => { // called when "bar" resolves the promise
})
.catch((err) => { //errors
});
```

If the first "then" block isn't returning another promise, I don't think the 2nd block will be called.